# IMPORTANT: Is swearing/cursing haram if you’re not insulting anyone?

Tags: halal-haram

This is one of the biggest dilemmas I have to face in my entire life, and I have researched online for an answer but I could not find a clear reason or answer for my question.

So basically I am 20 years old and I am running a successful E-commerce store where I sell a product by mass marketing it on large pages on Instagram. This business has the potential to change my life as whenever I use this advertisement, I end up making alot of money. The thing is however, the video contains the words “f it” basically in the context where the person is fed up and saying screw this, not offending anyone or anything,its just a phrase to showcase a certain emotion in order to show the product I am selling properly. The f word in this context isn’t used to offend or curse anyone but simply there, I would like to know if I use this ad will it be haram for me and would I be earning haram money? Really need your help with this.

Comment: If the actor can adequately convey emotion, saying "*forget it*" instead should work just as well. And if it doesn't, that indicates that you used the F-word specifically for the effect of its shock value. If you have to use that word, it's yourself that you are insulting.

Answer (score 0):

As to this fatwa
https://islamqa.org/hanafi/muftisays/10428/swear-words/
Using swear words without offending anybody is possibly haram and at least makruh and it should be avoided.